Pass a list in a Runnable in Langchain
I created a small app using langchain in which I combine RAG with chat history. I'm trying to pass a ChatMessageHistory() into a chain, but I get the following error:
TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'list'>
I know the error but I do not know how to fix it.
The code:
def process_chat(question, retriever):

    template = """
        
        Use the concrete examples of thought and action as a guide for the creation of the ontology.
        Examples: 

        {context}

        END OF EXAMPLES

        The history of discussion is the following: 
        
        {chat_history}

        END OF CHAT HISTORY

        Question: {question}
    """

    custom_rag_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)

    rag_chain = (
        {"context": retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough(), "chat_history": chat_history}
        | custom_rag_prompt
        | model
        | StrOutputParser()
    )
    response = rag_chain.invoke({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
    return response

I tried to use PlaceHolder but it didn't work

I believe format_docs is a custom function, right? Does it return a list? In such case, return it stringified.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.
